# Jekyll images getting wrong url on release (not on localhost)

Tags: html, image, jekyll

I just tryed to release my first Jekyll site from localhost to a live version and got some img-url problems. I have got a image folder in the root that contains a subfolder called staff where I get my staffmembers images.

My problem is that when I loop through my staff members on the `staff.html`
the page tryes to get the images from:

**mysite/staff.html/images/staff/img1.png**

... when the image accually is in:

**mysite/images/staff/img1.png**

The `staff.html` file looks like this:

```
 {% for member in members %}
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-3">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="{{ member.img }}" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="{{member.name}}">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">{{ member.name }}</h4>
              <ul>
                <li><b>{{ member.position }} <br> {{ member.section }}</b></li>
                <li><a href="mailto:{{ member.email }}"> {{ member.email }} </a></li>
                <hr>
                <li>Mobil: {{ member.mobil }}</li>
                <li>Kontor: {{ member.office }}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

I also have a folder in the root called '_staff' that contains .md files for all staff members that looks like this:

```
name: Jon doe
position: supervisor 
section: carpenter
email: jon@site.se
mobil: 073-000 00 00
office: 08-000 00 00
img: images/staff/img1.jpeg
```

any ideas how to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `images/staff/img` with `/images/staff/img`. The first slash tells the server to look in the root (top folder of the website).

Tip: You could/should also check that you set `permalink: pretty` in your _config.yml file. That should hide the .html exentsion in your URL's. [Source](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/)

Comment: Yeah good idea on hiding extensions on url. It's better looking